# How to copy from Excel to WYSIWYG Editor without styles?

Tags: excel, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm trying to copy an Excel table (nothing fancy, just text) to a WYSIWYG editor, like CKEditor for WordPress.

But when I do it, I see the table is copied with `width` and `height` attributes. So the HTML source looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:483px;" width="483">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col span="4" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr height="19">
            <td height="19" style="height:19px;width:227px;">
```

the attributes for `<table>` tag can be edited from the text editor itself, but what about the tr and td attributes? How do I remove the style from them?

I just want the plain data like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is this about the WYSIWYG editor's settings itself ?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of about the editor setting. When you copy in Excel, it puts the data into the Windows clipboard in a few different formats. One of those formats is plain text, another is HTML, and there's probably some proprietary binary format in there two.

When you past in another application, it has a priority for which format it wants. Your editor might look for HTML first. If there's an HTML format, it grabs it. If the copied data couldn't be represented as HTML by the Windows clipboard, your editor might go to the #2 format on its list - maybe plain text.

If you want to control how Excel tables are converted to HTML, you have to do it yourself. This code converts an Excel range to an html table.

```
Sub CopyRangeToHtmlTable()

    Dim doClip As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim vaTable As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim aTable() As String
    Dim aRow() As String

    'Read range into array
    vaTable = Sheet1.Range("A1:B4").Value

    'set up array to hold all of the rows
    ReDim aTable(1 To UBound(vaTable, 1))

    'loop through the rows
    For i = LBound(vaTable, 1) To UBound(vaTable, 1)
        'set up array to hold all of the tds
        ReDim aRow(1 To UBound(vaTable, 2))
        'loop through the tds
        For j = LBound(vaTable, 2) To UBound(vaTable, 2)
            aRow(j) = Tag(vaTable(i, j), "td")
        Next j
        'add the row to the table array
        aTable(i) = Tag(Join(aRow, vbNullString), "tr")
    Next i

    'put the table into the clipboard
    Set doClip = New MSForms.DataObject
    doClip.SetText Tag(Join(aTable, vbNewLine), "table", , True)
    doClip.PutInClipboard

End Sub

Public Function Tag(ByVal sValue As String, _
    ByVal sTag As String, _
    Optional sAttr As String = "", _
    Optional bIndent As Boolean = False) As String

    Dim sReturn As String

    If Len(sAttr) > 0 Then
        sAttr = Space(1) & sAttr
    End If

    If bIndent Then
        sValue = vbTab & Replace(sValue, vbNewLine, vbNewLine & vbTab)
        sReturn = "<" & sTag & sAttr & ">" & vbNewLine & sValue & vbNewLine & "</" & sTag & ">"
    Else
        sReturn = "<" & sTag & sAttr & ">" & sValue & "</" & sTag & ">"
    End If

    Tag = sReturn

End Function
```

When I paste into Notepad, it comes out like

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Number</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tom</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dick</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Harry</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dreamweaver, you can save your Excel file as a CSV file and then import it. Go to File > Import > Tabular Data. This works with files that are too large to copy and paste into Dreamweaver's Design view, which is my normal approach. If you're not using Dreamweaver, you can paste it into something like [Mr. Data Converter](http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) and output it as unstyled HTML.